# Can ExpressionEngine handle nested menus?

Tags: categories

I'm creating a web store, and have set up nested categories to make the menu system (example):

```
Home:
  - Categories:
      * Living room
      * Bathroom
Computers:
  - Categories:
      * CPU
      * RAM
  - Ready-made computers:
      * Gamer Starter
      * Gamer Extreme
```

Because of the structure, a simple `ul>li+ul>li`-structure will not suffice. Is it possible to use custom HTML with this structure? This is what I've done so far, but it's messy and not quite working...

```
<ul>
    {exp:channel:categories channel="top_menu" style="linear"}
    {if parent_id == 0}
    <?php $parent_id = '{category_id}'; ?>
    <li>
        <a href="{path='store/category'}">{category_name}</a>
        <div class="big_menu">
            <div class="left">...</div>
            <div class="right">
    {/if}
            <div>
            {if {parent_id} == '<?php echo $parent_id; ?>'}
            <?php $parent_2_id = '{category_id}'; ?>
            <h2>{category_name}</h2>
            {/if}
            {if {parent_id} == '<?php echo $parent_2_id; ?>'}
            <a href="{path='store/category'}">{category_name}</a>
            {/if}
            </div>
            <!-- Will not work because this always happens before the preceding code... -->
            {if parent_id == 0}
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    {/if}
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the 'nested' parameter instead of 'linear'? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/categories.html#channel-categories-style

Comment: @Romans-8---31-39 The problem is that the "nested" parameter generates an unordered list. The menu I'm trying to make, is like this: The top level items are laid out in a ul>li-layout. When you hover a top level item, a big window is revealed. Here multiple second and third level items are laid out. So a simple ul>li-setup doesn't work here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using GWcode Categories, http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories, to create menu, list from the ExpressionEngine categories. It's working fine, powerful plugin, the doc is very good.

you can use too the category menu http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#id27 :

{category_menu}
  Categories
  
    {select_options}
  
{/category_menu}

Or using the Query module: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/

Comment: Are you serious? Have I paid $300 for a system where you cannot even make A MENU without using 3rd party plugin?

Comment: The gwcode-categories plugin worked perfectly. Now I've got the format I want.